# Diagonalization of the matrix of a linear application and search for a base.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let be $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ a linear application between two vectors, such that  $f(\overrightarrow{u})= A_{f}\overrightarrow{u}$. Where $A_{f}$ is the next square matrix:

$$A_{f} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 5\\ 
0 & 2 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I need to calculate a vector space base containing the application kernel and a vector base such that the matrix associated with application $f$ is diagonal.

I've done the following:

1) We know, by definition, that the nucleus is the set of vectors whose image is the null vector. In mathematical language,

$ker f := \left \{ \vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{3} : f(\vec{u}) = \vec{0}\right \}$

Then, we need the vectors such that when multiplied by the matrix A they give the null vector

$A_{f}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\
$

We solve the system of linear equations, and it gives us as a solution:

$ker f = \left \langle \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right \rangle
$

2) I know how to diagonalize the matrix $A_{f}$, but I don't know how to get the base from which the matrix is diagonal. The exercise says that the matrix it gives us is calculated with respect to the standard base.

[In the link, I command you to diagonalization. I've done it in $\LaTeX{}$ code and won't let me insert it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRYM.png)
Once I get the diagonalization, I don't know how to find the base.

Answer (score 1):

By definition eigenvector satisfies the equation 
$$
A(v) = \lambda v
$$

So you just have to find the kernel of the matricx $A-\lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is one eigennvalue and $I$ the identity matrix

Comment: So, the base we're looking for is this: https://screenshots.firefox.com/Od6kqaUyI4O8uAFW/www.symbolab.com  ?

Comment: yes, you are right.